# Параметры функции по умолчанию

Tags: javascript

В стандарте ES-2015 появилась возможность задавать параметры функции по умолчанию, выглядит это так:

```
function name(name = 'noname') {
  console.log(name);
}
name()
```

Однако такого же эффекта можно было добиться с помощью хака:

```
function name(name) {
  var name = name || 'noname'
  console.log(name);
}
name()
```

При этом Babel транслирует такую функцию вот так:

```
function name() {
  var name = arguments.length > 0 && arguments[0] !== undefined ? arguments[0] : 'noname';
  console.log(name);
}
name();
```

Какой вариант правильнее: как предлагает Babel или с использованием логического `||`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильнее как бабель, разумеется. Потому что например:

```
> "" || "default"
-> "default"
```

и если вы захотите в свою функцию передать пустую строку, то поведение её будет слегка неожиданным.

Answer (score 3):

Логическое ИЛИ подчиняется законам логики. В общем случае такое поведение не подходит. Babel транспилирует не зная ничего о Вашей бизнес логике.

*Например, является ли пустая строка валидным значением или её нужно заменить значением по умолчанию? А 0?*

```js
let tests = [undefined, null, 0, '', false, NaN];

const test1 = (a = 42) => a;
const test2 = (a) => (a=a||42, a);

console.log(tests.map(test1));
console.log(tests.map(test2));
```

Answer (score 2):

правильнее писать не опираясь на `babel` так как

1. *как говорилось выше* `babel` ничего не знает о вашей логике
2. и самое главное это `babel`  всего лишь обертка которая в будущем станет не нужна (в идеале) и когда стандарт **ES-2015** станет стандартом дефакто то и надобность в `babel` отпадет

Comment: да я тоже думаю что надо использовать по максимуму новый стандарт

Comment: Мне кажется вы путаете. Вопрос был в эквивалентности указанных подходов. Бабель и должен ничего не знать о вашей логике, он должен соответствовать стандарту, т.е. ваш код должен вести себя так как вы ожидаете от стандартного кода ES6/7.